# How to plot a list of plots in a grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

At the moment I wish to plot multiple plots in the same window, using ggplot2. I've searched on the Internet and I found out that the `gridExtra::grid.arrange` function will do the job.

For it to work, I have to include each plot in the argument as `gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,plot3,...,plotN)`. But, what if I would like to make a more generic use of this function and would like to enter a list of plots? `myList <- list(plot1,plot2,...plotN)`

Inputing a list of plots and inputing in the form of `unlist(myList)` in the function gives an error. So, would would be the solution for this problem?

Comment: I use `cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = ...)`

Comment: u can use `gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = myList)` or the answer @Jack Brookes. I also prefer `cowplot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For grid.arrange() to work, you need to explicitly define the grobs argument.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
                 y1 = runif(100),
                 y2 = runif(100)^2)

plot_list <- list(
    plot1 = ggplot(df, aes(x, y1)) + geom_point(),
    plot2 = ggplot(df, aes(x, y2)) + geom_point()
    )

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list)
```